# Combining automatic and manual export package selection in Maven bundle plugin

Tags: java, maven, osgi, bundle, maven-bundle-plugin

Maven bundle plugin, as I know, will automatically add export/import package information to your bundle `manifest.mf` file, according to it sources.

Sometimes you need manually specify export-packages for example if you want to add `*.impl` packages, which maven-bundle-plugin will not include automatically. 
But if you specify packages in `<Export-Package>` tag, automatic export would not be performed.
If I have only one package that requires to be declared manually and other could be added to export-package block automatically by this plugin.
So I want to use automatically generated export-package manifest and add to it manually specified packages.

How can I turn on automatic generation of export info while I using manual?

Answer (score 2):

The Export-Package instruction can use wildcards. It takes all packages on the classpath and will then apply the glob expression to this list. So you can do:

```
  <Export-Package>com.example.myimpl.*, com.example.other.*</Export-Package>
```

It is not recommended to use * because this will include the whole transitive classpath.

Comment: It's a good feature. But it is not actually what i need. I can specify several packages at once by wildcard, but it would not help to keep automatically generated export-import info. When i use Export-Package (even with a wildcard), aytomaticaly generated info will be replaced by packages, specified in this tag.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want

Comment: If not specify <Export-Package> tag, Maven Bundle Plugin will generate manifest info automatically, according to project dependencies and class usages in your code. This info would not be included into manifest if you add <Export-Package> tag.

Comment: I think I understand (I dislike maven's defaults so would never use them, the JAR layout must imho be consciously designed, not ad-hoc). Anyway, you can also use -exportcontents, same syntax as Export-Package but is only applied for calculating the manifest.